# Changing the localization

Tags: date

I have SSH access to a CentOS 6.3 box.

Some results on that SSH and I think the whole OS is localized to portuguese.

When I type date, for example, I get

```
Sex Fev 15 02:35:48 WET 2013
```

instead of

```
Fri Feb 15... bla bla
```

the timezone is correct but this localization in portuguese is giving me problems with scripts using date, because they are not recognizing this as a date.

how can I change the date back to english format?

thanks.

---

edit: typing locale gives me this

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the LC_ALL variable to an english locale. Here is an example:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The locale must be present on the machine. If it is not, you can fallback to the POSIX C locale:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) describes how the locale variables should work.

Answer (score 2):

There are three levels of locale settings in the environment:

- If `LC_ALL` is set, it trumps everything.
- If an `LC_xxx` variable it sets and `LC_ALL` is unset, the value of `LC_xxx` applies to this category.
- If neither `LC_ALL` nor the relevant `LC_xxx` is set, `$LANG` applies.
- If none of the above applies, the locale is `C` (that's the most basic, no-frills locale).

As a user, you can define `LANG` and override a particular setting with `LC_xxx`. For example, to work in a Portuguese locale except with British dates:

```
export LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_TIME=en_UK.UTF-8
```

(Put that in your `~/.profile`.)

Instead of setting `LANG`, you might set just the categories you're interested in. For example, to get messages in Portuguese and use the UTF-8 character set but leave other formats to their default value:

```
unset LANG
export LC_MESSAGES=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.UTF-8
```

If you need to run a program that can't cope with locale variations, run it in the `C` locale.

```
LC_ALL=C troublesome_script
```